# Group columns by the same value and update

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table with a few columns which only (number and index are important of) and a few rows.

```
|number|index|line|
| 1234 | blue| 0  |
| 1234 | blue| 1  |
| 567  | blue| 0  |
```

I'm trying to update the rows where the index = blue into index = red, but the columns "number" AND "index" are not allowed to be the same. I've tried grouping the columns together and if the column number = number and index = index then return a false statement

How can I achieve this?

Expected result:

```
|number|index|line|
|1234  |blue |0   |
|1234  |blue |1   |
|567   |red  |0   |
```

Answer (score -1):

You could update the minimum value to `red`:

```
update t join
       (select min(number) as min_number
        from t
        where index = 'blue'
       ) tt
       on t.number = tt.min_number and t.index = 'blue'
    set index = 'red';
```